# Amazon S3 usage reports per bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Are there any good AWS Usage Report parsers that will separate S3 usage per bucket, in a more human-readable form? Right now, you can export the usage exports into an XML or CSV file, but these are not human-friendly at all.

I realize one method is to have multiple accounts, linked together with consolidated billing, but this is not especially scalable (you need to send AWS an e-mail if you want to consolidate more than 20 accounts).

Comment: http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/06/announcing-ice-cloud-spend-and-usage.html

Comment: awesome! going to try that out.